AdonisJS Lucid ORM - pivot table between 3 models
I have 3 models
User
id
name
phone
Application
id
name
Permission
id
name
In addition, I have a pivot table between all of them, such a user has some applications, and for each application, he has the relevant permission.
Different users can use the same application with different permissions.
Table named: user_application_permission
Now I created 3 models:
User:
import { compose } from '@adonisjs/core/helpers'
import { column } from '@adonisjs/lucid/orm'
import Base from '#models/base'

export default class User extends compose(Base) {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  declare id: number

  @column()
  declare name: string | null

  @column()
  declare phone: string  
}

Application:
import { column, hasOne } from '@adonisjs/lucid/orm'
import Base from '#models/base'
import Permission from '#models/permission'
import type { HasOne } from '@adonisjs/lucid/types/relations'

export default class Application extends Base {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  declare id: number

  @column()
  declare name: string

  @column()
  declare status: number

  @hasOne(() => Permission)
  permission: HasOne<typeof Permission>
}

Permission:
import { belongsTo, column } from '@adonisjs/lucid/orm'
import Base from '#models/base'
import Application from '#models/application'
import type { BelongsTo } from '@adonisjs/lucid/types/relations'

export default class Permission extends Base {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  declare id: number

  @column()
  declare name: string

  @column()
  declare parent_permission_id: number

  @belongsTo(() => Application)
  application: BelongsTo<typeof Application>
}

How can I use ManyToMany / ManyToManyTrough, to connect all together, such when I query the User I will get all its applications with the permission?
Thanks!
Failed to use ManyToMany cause I don't know how to use 3 models at once
